# first part of the array dosent save the students score and the alert box says the student name and undefined or NaN

Tags: javascript, arrays, function

Here is the code:

```js
 function studentName(x)
 {
  while(x == '')
  {
   x = prompt('Cannot leave field blank. Enter again');
   
  }
  return(x)
 } 

 
 function studentScore(y)
 {
  while(y == '' || y > 100 || y < 0 || isNaN(y))
  {
   y = parseFloat(prompt('Invalid score. Enter score again'));
  }
  return(y)
 }

 
 function another(z,t)
 {
  while(z == '' && z != 'n' && z != 'N' && z != 'y' && z != 'Y')
  {
   
   if(z == 'y' || z == 'Y')
   {
    z = prompt('Invalid Option. Enter another score? Y or N')
   }
   else
   {
    t = prompt('Invalid Option. Enter another student? Y or N')
   }
  }
  return(z)
 }
   
 var names = [] 
 var scores = []
 var redo = true
 var anotherName
 var redo2
 var retry = true
 var anotherScore
 var retry2
 var i = 0
 var a = 1
  while(redo == true)
  {
   var studentNames = prompt('Enter student name');
     var name = studentName(studentNames);
     names.push(name)
   while(retry == true)
   {
    var studentScores = parseFloat(prompt('Enter student score'));
    var score = score + studentScore(studentScores);

    retry = prompt('Enter another score? Y/N');
    retry2 = another(retry);
    if(retry == 'y' || retry == 'Y')
    {
     retry = true
     a++
    }
    else if(retry == 'n' || retry == 'N')
    {
     retry = false
    }
   }
   score = score / a
   scores[i] = score
   redo = prompt('Enter another student? Y/N');
   redo2 = another(redo);

   if(redo == 'y' || redo == 'Y')
   {
    redo = true
    retry = true
    i++;
    a = 1
    score = 0
   }
   else if(redo == 'n' || redo == 'N')
   {
    redo = false
   } 
  }
  
  for(y=0; y < names.length; y++)
  {
   alert(names[y] + " - " + scores[y]);
  }
```

Try running the code to understand it is a problem that's hard to describe but basically, what I think is happening is the array dosen't store the first score correctly because it keeps saying the students name as the name and the score either is NaN or undefined

Answer (score 0):

Please initialize score outside of loop and remove var keyword from loop.

```html
<script>
function studentName(x)
{
    while(x == '')
    {
        x = prompt('Cannot leave field blank. Enter again');

    }
    return(x)
} 


function studentScore(y)
{
    while(y == '' || y > 100 || y < 0 || isNaN(y))
    {
        y = parseFloat(prompt('Invalid score. Enter score again'));
    }
    return(y)
}


function another(z,t)
{
    while(z == '' && z != 'n' && z != 'N' && z != 'y' && z != 'Y')
    {

        if(z == 'y' || z == 'Y')
        {
            z = prompt('Invalid Option. Enter another score? Y or N')
        }
        else
        {
            t = prompt('Invalid Option. Enter another student? Y or N')
        }
    }
    return(z)
}

var names = []  
var scores = []
var redo = true
var anotherName
var redo2
var retry = true
var anotherScore
var retry2
var i = 0
var a = 1
    while(redo == true)
    {
        var studentNames = prompt('Enter student name');
                var name = studentName(studentNames);
                names.push(name)
                var score = 0;
        while(retry == true)
        {
            var studentScores = parseFloat(prompt('Enter student score'));
            score = score + studentScore(studentScores);

            retry = prompt('Enter another score? Y/N');
            retry2 = another(retry);
            if(retry == 'y' || retry == 'Y')
            {
                retry = true
                a++
            }
            else if(retry == 'n' || retry == 'N')
            {
                retry = false
            }
        }
        score = score / a
        scores[i] = score
        redo = prompt('Enter another student? Y/N');
        redo2 = another(redo);

        if(redo == 'y' || redo == 'Y')
        {
            redo = true
            retry = true
            i++;
            a = 1
            score = 0
        }
        else if(redo == 'n' || redo == 'N')
        {
            redo = false
        } 
    }

    for(y=0; y < names.length; y++)
    {
        alert(names[y] + " - " + scores[y]);
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

When your loop runs this line for the first time:

```
var score = score + studentScore(studentScores);
```

The variable `score` is not defined yet, so the above line results in a `NaN`.

To fix, simple define `score` before your loop:

```
var score = 0;
```